# Create multiboot USB drive from Debian (Linux+Windows & BIOS+UEFI)

Tags: debian, windows, usb-drive, multiboot

I'm trying to create a multiboot USB drive that supports UEFI and BIOS legacy boot with (at least) Windows 10 and Debian 9 on it from Debian (sid).

Is it possible ? If so, what is the tool/process to make it ?

Comment: You can try [MultiBootUSB](http://multibootusb.org/)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't personally found a single tool that does multiboot successfully. I guess I have an unfortunate BIOS on one of my computers...

The best guide I've seen for UEFI and BIOS is from the [Arch Linux Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Multiboot_USB_drive#Hybrid_UEFI_GPT_+_BIOS_GPT/MBR_boot).

You would need create a hybrid MBR, format at least one partition with FAT, install GRUB for EFI and BIOS, and configure grub for each mount image.

I never learned enough grub syntax to make a reasonable multiboot setup. Sorry I can't help further with that.

Personally I'd rather boot a VM...

Answer (score 0):

I know only one program that supports Linux and Windows live-systems. It is `yumi`. But it have only windows version. But some peoples say that it’s possible running on Linux through WINE